# Windows Forms find all the active Form instance types

Tags: winforms

WinForms, how to find all the active windows of specific instance type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do something like this using LINQ:

```
var forms = from f in Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form1>()
            select f;
```

Or if you had additional criteria, something like:

```
var forms = from f in Application.OpenForms.OfType<CustomerForm>()
            where f.HasChanges
            select f;
```